# How to write an expression that evaluates a pipeline parameter to TRUE/FALSE?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline parameter fed by a config file in SQL.
Sometimes that parameter will be empty, not NULL but just empty ('').

How do I write an expression that will evaluate the parameter to TRUE/FALSE(blank/not blank) that I can put into my IF activity?

Basic question but thanks a lot.

I tried
@pipeline().parameters.x = ''
but it just told me Parameter x = '' was not found .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below expression in the if activity to evaluate a parameter is empty or not.

```
@empty(pipeline().parameters.ok)
```

**Sample demonstration:**

A sample parameter `ok`.

[image]

For example, purpose I have created a string variable which I will use inside if to check the output.

In if give the above expression.

[image]

Inside True activities I have given a set variable activity and gave some value and did the same inside false activities.

[image]

[image]

**Output when the parameter value is not given(empty).**

[image]

**Output when we gave any value to the parameter**

[image]